# SublimeText completion fails inside HTML attributes

Tags: html, autocomplete, sublimetext, emmet

SublimeText completion using .sublime-completions file fails to work on HTML attribute, inside the quotes. Typing the trigger (`test` in the example below) inside the `alt=""` attribute does not insert the completion. It does outside the image tag without problems. Any suggestions why?

Scope inside the quotes is matching the definition in the `html-attr.sublime-completions` file below: `text.html.basic meta.tag.inline.any.html string.quoted.double.html punctuation.definition.string.end.html`.

```
<body>
  <img src="/images/poster.jpg" alt="">
</body>
```

I am using .sublime-completions file:

```
// html-attr.sublime-completions 
{
  "scope": "text.html.basic meta.tag.inline.any.html string.quoted.double.html punctuation.definition.string.end.html",
  "completions":
  [
    {
      "trigger": "test",
      "contents": "test ok"
    }
  ]
}
```

Other installed packages include Emmet, HTML5, Better Completion, HTMLAttributes and SublimeCodeIntel, but disabling them all does not help the situation.

```
// Preferences.sublime-settings
{
    "auto_complete": true,
}
```

### Update:

Emmet could have been a culprit, but not my case. Emmet overrides completions defined by .sublime-completions files, unless Emmet's tab_abbreviation is disabled for the corresponding scope:

```
// Emmet.sublime-settings
"disable_tab_abbreviations_for_scopes": "text.html.basic"
```

I solved the problem temporarily by using .sublime-snippet, but it didn't work on the XML files so well. Still looking for an answer to the question above.

```
<!-- html-attr.sublime-snippet -->
<snippet>
  <content>test ok</content>
  <tabTrigger>test</tabTrigger>
  <scope>text.html.basic</scope>
  <description>html-attr.sublime-completion does not work</description>
</snippet>
```